# установка sudoers на linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Есть задание:

> На  ПК установить *sudoers* и попробовать воспользоваться этой командой, получив права *root*-a

Нашел я [статью](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B2_ubuntu) чтобы поменять, вроде бы доходчиво написано. На этапе, когда надо было перезапустить процесс:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

упал линукс (не запускался вообще). Чуть поморочившись через <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> восстановил.

Вопрос: есть у кого-то "проверенная статья" или знания по этой теме?

---

**UPD:** понял что конкретно мне нужно, но где было бы четко расписано, пока не нашел, только скудные примеры.

Поясню. Я создал пользователя `guru`,  задал ему пароль `123456`. Теперь хочу его кастомизировать следующим образом: чтобы у пользователя `guru` появилась,  скажем, возможность входить в директорию, которая создана другим пользователем (и `chmod 700`) при использовании `sudo`. Но чтобы других привилегий у него не было.

При использовании команды

```
sudo visudo
```

(от основного пользователя) открывается файл из настройками `sudo` доступов.

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Я хочу дописать следующее:

```
guru   ALL=( ... а в этом вопрос ... )
```

Какие существуют правила написания условий?

---

**UPD:** В общем, никак нельзя сделать так, как я хотел. Можно только прописать идентичное значение `guru`, то есть:

```
guru    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Потом прописать `sudo chmod 777 name_dir`, а потом уже можно будет зайти.
Если нужно было бы предоставить доступ к специфической проге то можно посмотреть в [статье](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)). Жаль что никто ссылки толковой не скинул раньше.

Comment: документация в полном порядке. судя по изложенному заданию, вы пытались сделать совершенно не то, что требуется: пытались запустить графический сеанс для пользователя root.

Comment: Нет, он ничего такого не пытался сделать. Он просто начал вбивать в консоль все примеры из статьи подряд. А приведенная им команда была вообще нужна для разрешения графического входа рута в систему :)

Comment: Да попробывал пару примеров, что в этом такого?) но когда ОС после выполнения примера упала, смотрю на ети примеры с опаской, потому как там полно предуприждений и без того.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем учебном задании вас попросили сделать доступной команду `sudo` - ту самую, которую вы столь лихо использовали для сноса системы. Вам не кажется, что довольно глупо устанавливать уже установленную программу?

Для того, чтобы просто начать делать задание, вам надо сначала найти дистрибутив линукса, в котором эта команда не предустановлена. Современных дистрибутивов без sudo, наверное, уже нет. Поэтому вам надо подойти к преподавателю (или кто там выдал вам такое задание) и попросить дистрибутив линукса у него.

Конечно, есть шанс, что задание было в чем-то другом, а вы даже не смогли его правильно переписать. В таком случае преподаватель сможет посмеяться...

Comment: Павел, скопировал без редакции вопрос:  >>>>>> Изучите, что такое sudoers, что такое команда sudo и как она работает.
Установите у себя на ПК sudoers и попробуйте воспользоваться этой командой, получив права root’a.<<<<<  думаю может было бы правильнее сформулировать создайте пользователя и через sudoers присвойте ему права. Как вы думаете?

Comment: В таком случае вы **уже** выполнили практическую часть задания. Столько раз, сколько команд из документации пробовали :) Очевидно же, что в такой формулировке вам всего-то и надо было написать `sudo` перед любой другой командой. Однако, изучить вопрос у вас определенно не получилось. Советую начать изучение с понимания того, кто вообще такой в линуксе `root` и зачем нужно получать его права. К примеру, можете попробовать выполнить все те же самые команды, но уже без `sudo`

Comment: *В таком случае преподаватель сможет посмеяться* — судя по тому, что в задании вместо *sudo* написано *sudoers*, преподаватель, боюсь, смеяться не будет.

Answer (score -1):

не `guru ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, а `sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` нужно прописать.

Comment: а кикие вобще правила написания правил доступа в этом файле? а то я  то я только по аналогии сделал.

Comment: Абсолютно наоборот. Сам настраивал sudo на дебиане, даже без интернета. Работает как часы, даже на sid.